# Erro de sintaxe PostgreSQL usando chaves

Tags: sql, postgresql, sintaxe

Estou com dificuldade para entender o porquê do pgadmin estar apontando erro de sintaxe na minha *query*.

```
select 
    first_name,
    coalesce(to_char(avg(p.amount),'99.99'), 'nnn') valor_medio
from
{
select 
    c.first_name as nome_cliente,
    c.last_name as sobrenome_cliente,
    to_char(avg(p.amount),'99.99') as media_valor, 
    s.first_name as nome_funcionario,
    s.last_name as sobrenome_funcionario
from 
    payment p 
    left join customer c on c.customer_id = p.customer_id
    left join staff s on s.staff_id = p.staff_id 
} as 
    tmp
    left join staff s on c.staff_id = p.staff_id
    where media_valor > 1
```

Essa query ainda está em formulação, mas aqui nesse ponto já está dando erro. Na mensagem do erro vem o seguinte:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 4: {
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 21
```

Já olhei diversas vezes na linha, mas ainda não consegui identificar o que está errado. Fiz uma questão muito parecida com essa, porém ela não apresentou tal erro. Eu queria saber qual o erro e o porque do mesmo estar sendo apontado.

Comment: De onde você tirou essas chaves?

Comment: cara, sinceramente não acredito.... não sei como as troquei por parenteses. Pior que fiz isso repetidas vezes, e a questão anterior usei parenteses. De fato, muita falta de atenção. Passou despercebido mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL não possui chaves em sua sintaxe. Use parenteses:

```
select 
    first_name,
    coalesce(to_char(avg(p.amount),'99.99'), 'nnn') valor_medio
from
(
select 
    c.first_name as nome_cliente,
    c.last_name as sobrenome_cliente,
    to_char(avg(p.amount),'99.99') as media_valor, 
    s.first_name as nome_funcionario,
    s.last_name as sobrenome_funcionario
from 
    payment p 
    left join customer c on c.customer_id = p.customer_id
    left join staff s on s.staff_id = p.staff_id 
) as 
    tmp
    left join staff s on c.staff_id = p.staff_id
    where media_valor > 1
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/SyntaxBraces.sql).

Comment: Já é a resposta correta, foi muita falta de atenção minha, não tinha reparado que havia trocado os parenteses (incrível isso)